# XCode 5 Table VIew Cell's Accessory -> Detail show nothing on iOS 6 device

Tags: uitableview, xcode5

I am migrating my app from iOS 6 to iOS 7. In XCode 5, I can see the Detail logo in the cell.
But, the reality is in iOS 6 device I can't see the Detail logo.

My App used to utilise Details Disclosure as accessory way. But, in iOS 7, it looks ugly. That is the reason I chosen Detail.

How to fix this?

[image: iOS 6] [image: iOS 7]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use accessoryView, put any button you want there, and it will look the same on both iOS versions

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "detail disclosure" accessory instead of just using the "detail" accessory directly on your storyboard:

[image]

The down side of doing this is that it takes more space on the tableview in iOS 7 but the good one is you don't need add a custom button and you can attach segue from storyboard.

[image]
[image]